# PNRP + dont see Global_ on Windows 7

Tags: .net, pnrp

Im trying to test out PNRP in a simple app that either registers or resolves.  On my Vista machine when i run  'netsh p2p pnrp cloud show list' .... I see Global_  When i try this from my Windows 7 machine i do not see Global_ i only have LinkLocal_...

I can see i have an IPV6 address on the Windows 7 machine (via ipconfig)

I may not just understand it enough yet - very poorly documented and most of the documentation is from Orca, 2007,etc.  Makes me wonder if PNRP will just end up being another uddi.microsoft.com (i know they are nothing alike, but my point is...)

Answer (score 0):

Do the following diagnostics:

1. Check whether you have a global ipv6 address. Type `ipconfig` and check for 2001: address. If you don't have one then type `netsh int ipv6 show teredo status` to check the reason for failure. If status is failed, install freenet6 to get a global ipv6 address.
2. Check whether PNRP is able to reach the seed server. Type this
   `netsh p2p pnrp  diagnostics  ping seed Global_`. If it fails, change your DNS to google dns (8.8.8.8).